# Meaning of 'years if not decades later'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading [this](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/monster-magnetar-pinpointed-as-trigger-of-ultrabright-stellar-detonation/) article of Scientific American.

Here is some of sentence.

> In 2017 they published a study with a number of theoretical
>   calculations that suggested a magnetar would first produce a
>   superluminous supernova—and then, **years if not decades later**,
>   produce a number of FRBs (although exactly how remains a mystery).

I can't understand what **years if not decades later** means really.

Does it mean a magnetar produce a number of FRBs after few years?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oxford Dictionary

**[if not](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/if_not)** [phrase]

> Perhaps even (used to introduce a more extreme term than one first
>   mentioned)
>
> *hundreds if not thousands of germs*

In your context, the period of time between the supernova and the FBRs could be **years**, and perhaps not just a few years but **decades**.

Applying the definition

First mentioned term: years
More extreme term: decades